# Как копировать выбранное изображение в нужную папку? Android

Tags: java, android

Использую следующий код для выбора изображения:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

Далее, в `onActivityResult()` мне нужно скопировать полученное изображение в папку. Какими методами я могу это сделать? Перепробовал уже все, что только пришло в голову. Метод `FileUtils.copy()` применить не получается.

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            File destination = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File source = new File(data.getData().toString());
            try
            {
                FileUtils.copy(source, destination);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Нашел решение:**

Поменял `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` на `ACTION_PICK`, потому второй вариант работает большем количестве моих устройств. А первый, в некоторых случаях, приходится менять на `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

**1.** В `onActivityResult`, создаем путь *"Fdestination"*, который ведет в корневую папку приложения и задает скопированному файлу имя *"sm_background.png"*. Создаем файл *"destination"* по пути *"Fdestination"*.

**2.**  Метод `getRealPathFromURI(data.getData())` - получаем путь к выбранному изображению и при помощи метода `copyFile` копируем его в корневую папку.

**3.** `Uri bg = Uri.fromFile(destination);` - получаем путь до скопированного изображения в корневой папке.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String Fdestination = getFilesDir()+"/sm_background.png";
            File destination = new File(Fdestination);
            try {
                copyFile(new File(getRealPathFromURI(data.getData())), destination);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            Uri bg = Uri.fromFile(destination);
        }
    }

    private void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
        if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
            return;
        }

        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        if (destination != null && source != null) {
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        }
        if (source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if (destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }


    }

    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {

        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: Вам не нужен метод `getRealPathFromURI`, любые его реализации не полны. Чтобы получить InputStream достаточно `context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`, еще можно через файловый дескриптор `context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")?.getFileDescriptor()`

Comment: Спасибо, учту :)